# How can I globally disable specific ray visibility settings on multiple objects at once?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, workflow, properties

I have a little scene and wanted to check the differences in render times and visuals by changing some of these cycles settings:

[image]

However, the scene consists out of many objects and it would take a long time to manually modify them all. Is there a way to do this with a few less clicks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are able to select all the objects you want to change a property for (adding them to a group can help with that), you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking a property to change that property on all the selected objects.

Comment: Thanks for this from 6 years in the future. Been using Blender for a decade, and I did not know you could do this until today. What a time-saver!